# Insert data from C# to XML with using Linq issue?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am building a C# application. I want to insert the following XML data to XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Employees>
  <Employee ID="1">
       <Name>Numeri</Name>
  </Employee>
  <Employee ID="2">
    <Name>Ismail</Name>
  </Employee>
  <Employee ID="3">
    <Name>jemu</Name>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```

Previously I have tried an XML that has not attribute value, But now I
 want to insert with attribute value.

```
string _file = (Application.StartupPath+"/employees.xml");
XDocument doc;

if (!File.Exists(_file))
{
    doc = new XDocument();
    doc.Add(new XElement("Employees"));
}
else
{
    doc = XDocument.Load(_file);
}

doc.Root.Add(
      new XElement("Employee",
                   new XElement("ID", textBox1.Text),
                   new XElement("Name", textBox2.Text)
            )
      );
doc.Save(_file);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `XAttribute` instead of `XElement` in order to insert `ID` as attribute:

```
doc.Root.Add(
      new XElement("Employee",
                   new XAttribute("ID", textBox1.Text),
                   new XElement("Name", textBox2.Text)
            )
      );
```